# Can "some" be more than 50%?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The word "some" has often the sense of "few" if given in a bound. Does this mean  more than 50%?
It would be good if some historical account mentioned, who uses "some" to be more than 50%?

Comment: “Some days I go to the gym; some days I don’t.” It stands to reason—since those two types of days are mutually exclusive and it’s not all that likely that I go to the gym _exactly_ every second day—that one of those _some_’s likely represents more than 50% of days, and the other less than 50% of days.

Comment: Definitely more than 50% but dated. http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Ecclesiasticus-44-9/  " And some there be, which have no memorial; who are perished, as though they had never been;"

Comment: To illustrate @JanusBahsJacquet's example with some real-life lyrics:[Some girls will, some girls won't
Some girls need a lot of lovin' and some girls don't](http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/r/racey/some_girls.html). Language is not mathematics.

Comment: The key word in the definition of [some](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/some) is *unspecified*.

Comment: "Some" can be 1% or 99%.  When you write you should probably restrict the use of "some" to less than 50%, but when you read you should make no such assumption.

Comment: it depends on context. In some contexts, it usually indicates less than 50%, in some it indicates more than one but less than all, in still others, it indicates more than 50%. The point is it's ambiguous and there are some viable examples of it being used for any quantity more than 1.

Comment: Can you give an example of the usage please?

Answer (score 4):

In all of the dictionaries that I checked, "some" is used for unspecified amounts and quantities, and also for "a considerable number or quantity." (AHD)  In none of the examples did it make sense to ask "what percentage are they talking about?"

Because it's used for unspecified things I don't think it makes sense to talk about number or percentage, even in situations where there is a finite amount of something.  For example someone gestures to a bowl of candy and says "Have some."  Does "some" mean more than half of the candy, or a few pieces?  It doesn't indicate because it's for an "unspecified amount."  Someone faced with a bowl of candy will probably take two or three pieces, regardless of whether the bowl contains 100 or 10 pieces.

"Some of the people in the professor's class didn't understand the lecture."  Does "some" mean more than 50%?  No, it means an unspecified number.

You asked who uses "some" to mean more than 50%.  I don't think anyone does because the word means a vague amount with no number attached.  If they were referring to a group of 4 people and said "some people." it could mean anything; one, two or three people.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematical probabilities and history aside, ***"some"*** has an uncertain feeling which would lead to the assumption that it meant: 'less than the majority.' To refer to more than 50%, it would be more common to use ***"most of..."***. (US)

Comment: I don't even really think the uncertainty of _some_ leads to an assumption that it refers to something less than the majority. It doesn't to me, at least. It's not likely to be an overwhelming majority (“Some US presidents have been white” seems odd), but as long as the ratio is relatively balanced, a majority wouldn't be odd or non-assumed necessarily. “Some universities offer free scholarship programs” seems fine to me, for instance, though I have no idea if the actual number is 10% or 85%. The fact that it's a vague, uncertain number is the only thing I'd assume.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet all these measure terms are vague but with their different nuances: one, a couple, few, a few, some, several, many, most, all (that's how I order them). Of course with any particular set they may overlap, and some of one set may be more than most of another set. But for one set, 'some' if forced at gunpoint, is usually not more than 50%. In that instance one would use 'most'. Of course, in logic/math, 'some' means anything more than 'at least one' up to 'all' which is more than 50%.

Answer (score 1):

If the sentence with "most" instead of "some" is true and that matters, you shouldn't use "some".  This is due to Grice's maxim of quantity:

> Make your contribution as informative as is required (for the current purposes of the exchange).
>       Do not make your contribution more informative than is required.

from [Cooperative Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle).

However, what matters is whether "some" would be misleading.  It will be okay even if more than 50% holds, provided you clarify.  For instance, you could say "some, in fact most".

Answer (score 0):

In precise mathematical language, *some* just means more than 0. In particular, *every* is a special case of *some*.

In a sense this is also true in normal language, though there is a general (not absolute) rule that whenever there is a more specific and equally or more common word, it should be preferred. Just like you usually don't say *parent* when talking about your mother, you also usually don't say *some* when you could say *most* or even *every/all*. Consequently, when you say *some*, the recipient of your message will usually assume that since you didn't say *most* or *all*, these more specific words don't apply. However, there are contexts such as hypothetical assumptions in which it doesn't work that way. These are particularly frequent in mathematics and in laws, which is why mathematicians and lawyers probably find it easier to accept that *every* is technically a special case of *some*.